# Disable legend hover in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to disable the hover attribute of legend items because I am using Highcharts on mobile platforms. Sadly, making a legendItemClick event does not solve the problem as hovering still occurs.

I was encouraged to see that this issue came up on the old support site for highcharts back in 2011. The thread can be found [here](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13373). I was particularly glad to see the last jfiddle example and the function declared in it.

Unfortunately, the only thing that worked for me was the workaround of changing the setHoverStyle to null. This isn't great though since the hover action still fires and makes navigating the legend and chart unresponsive. The rest of the suggestions in the above thread resulted in the chart not being rendered.

Granted, it might be because I had a difficult time translating the example to my purposes - honestly, I do not know where to call the function and everywhere I have tried has failed. My JavaScript file is set up along the lines of

```
var chartDefinition = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart_content',
    type: 'column'
  },
  colors: [
         '#619ED6',
         '#6BA547',
         '#F7D027',
         '#E48F1B',
         '#B77EA3',
         '#E64345',
         '#60CEED',
         '#9CF168',
         '#F7EA4A',
         '#FBC543',
         '#FFC9ED',
         '#E6696E'
         ],
  title: {
    text: ''
  },

  ...

 column: {
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      events: {
        click: function() { return false; },
        legendItemClick: function() { return false; }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        color: '#222',
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
          fontSize: '13px',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: []
};
```

Listing and setting the various highcharts attributes.

Does anyone know how to disable this hover attribute or where the proper place would be to call the [function](http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/Cp7xh/1/)?

Comment: By the way, why bother styling dataLabels if you're setting it to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few solutions to implement this. There's no built-in option to change that (as of 06.2022).

1. Try to disable mouseover for `legendGroup`, not `legendItem`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp7xh/10/

2. Disable pointer-events in CSS:

```css
.highcharts-legend {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ebrodhk4/

3. A plugin that prevents Highcharts Core from adding events:

Plugin:

```js
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(
        H.Legend.prototype,
        'init',
        function(proceed, chart, options) {
            
            if (options.enableMouseTracking === false) {
                this.setItemEvents = false;
            }
            
            proceed.apply(this, [chart, options]);
        }
    );
})(Highcharts);
```

Usage:

```js
    legend: {
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        itemStyle: {
            cursor: 'auto'
        }
    },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ogqv2sya/

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your answer. This indeed gets rid of the legend items becoming bold when hovering over them. It seems, though, like the hover event is still triggering. The cursor changes over the legend items in the jsfiddle example and on the mobile device the legend is still unresponsive. Any way to get rid of hovering completely? Thanks!

Comment: I have just tested on SG3 and works perfectly fine. Pointer show up because of CSS styles..

Comment: Thanks Pawel! Upon reevaluation your suggestion worked out perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution, but it feels pretty hacky. Shouldn't there be a `enableMouseTracking` property over the `legend` or something?

Comment: It is a bit hacky: removes events added by the core. There is also other hacky solution: [prevent firing events using CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ebrodhk4/).

In the answer above, I have added also another solution: [a plugin that adds `enableMouseTracking`](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ogqv2sya/).

If you want this feature in the library, I recommend creating a "Feature request" on Highchart's GH: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: Updated my answer above. Let me know if you create a ticket on GH, I will attach it to the answer. The more "thumbs up" ticket gathers, the more likely option will be implemented