# High charts / Stacked Bar - Legends Disable hover

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

We have implemented high chart - Stacked bar as below -

```
const options = {
        chart: {
                ….
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            visible: false,
            categories: ['']
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            visible: false,
            …….
        },      
        legend: {
            itemStyle: {
                cursor: 'default',
                fontWeight: 'normal'
            },
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'default',
                stacking: 'normal',
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return false;
                    }   
                },

                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false                      
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: false,
            outside: true,
            followPointer: true,
            crosshairs: false,
        },
        accessibility: {
             …….
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: props.series
    };
```

It loads fine, also hovering on any of the block does not change opacity for other blocks.

How can we disable hovering on legends below stacked bar?

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/clockworked247/FGmgC/

In above link, basically hover effect on John, Joe, Jane, Janet legends need to be disabled.

Comment: Would be good if you can share a fiddle

Comment: Sure, in this example - I could like to disable hover animation for legends John, Joe etc. Link here - http://jsfiddle.net/clockworked247/FGmgC/

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535599/disable-legend-hover-in-highcharts

Comment: Above link should help. If you are looking for more solutions you can also achieve it using CSS. Make pointer event none for legends like `.highcharts-legend-item:{ pointer-events:none; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all.

Below answer helped, and worked.

Above link should help. If you are looking for more solutions you can also achieve it using CSS. Make pointer event none for legends like .highcharts-legend-item:{ pointer-events:none; }

Comment: It's actually the only solution that worked for me!